# C++ Keyboard Controller

Tags: c++, sdl

I've written a Controller for the keyboard so that I can map certain keys to callbacks within a game. A key can only call one callback, but a callback can be called by many keys.

Currently, a Controller has two `std::map`s - one for when the key(s) is pressed/held, and one for when the key(s) are released. These maps are `SDL_Scancode` to `std::string` (Which I may change later to an enum rather than a string? But strings are easier to read so maybe not.) The Controller also has a `ControllerContext` object, which is just a wrapper around two `std::map`s of `std::string` to `std::function<void(void)>`: one map for callbacks to happen when a key is pressed, another for callbacks to happen when a key is released.

I feel like some kind of change could be made to make the code more readable, and I am unsure of if I should have the context stored in a `shared_ptr`, or if I should just keep a raw pointer within the Controller.

This is how it would work:

```
//An event union provided by SDL
//https://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdlevent.html
SDL_Event e;
//A controller
Controller controller_;
ControllerContext context_;

//Build the context
controller_.SetContext(&context);

//Poll all events in the event queue, feeding them to the structure e
while(SDL_PollEvent(&e))
{
   switch(e.type)
       case SDL_KEYDOWN:
           controller_.OnKeyPress(e.key);
           break;
       case SDL_KEYUP:
           controller_.OnKeyRelease(e.key);
           break;
       default: 
           break;
}
```

keyboardcontroller.h

```
#ifndef SHMUPPY_HEADER_KEYBOARDCONTROLLER_H_
#define SHMUPPY_HEADER_KEYBOARDCONTROLLER_H_

#include <map>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <string>
#include <memory>


struct ControllerContext;

class Controller
{
public:
    Controller();

    int OnKeyPress(const SDL_Event &e);

    int OnKeyRelease(const SDL_Event &e);

    void SetContext(std::shared_ptr<ControllerContext> context_);

protected:
    std::map<SDL_Scancode, std::string> keypress_action_map_;
    std::map<SDL_Scancode, std::string> keyrelease_action_map_;
    std::shared_ptr<ControllerContext> controller_context_;
};


#endif
```

keyboardcontroller.cpp

```
#include "KeyboardController.h"
#include "ControllerContext.h"


Controller::Controller()
{
    //Some test initializations
    keypress_action_map_[SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT] = "Left";
    keypress_action_map_[SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN] = "Down";
    keypress_action_map_[SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT] = "Right";
    keypress_action_map_[SDL_SCANCODE_UP] = "Up";


    keyrelease_action_map_[SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT] = "Left";
    keyrelease_action_map_[SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN] = "Down";
    keyrelease_action_map_[SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT] = "Right";
    keyrelease_action_map_[SDL_SCANCODE_UP] = "Up";
}

int Controller::OnKeyPress(const SDL_Event& e)
{
    try
    {
        //std::cout << keypress_action_map_.at(e.key.keysym.scancode) << std::endl;
        controller_context_->keypress_events_.at(keypress_action_map_.at(e.key.keysym.scancode))();
        return 1;
    }
    catch (std::exception ex)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

int Controller::OnKeyRelease(const SDL_Event& e)
{
    try
    {
        std::cout << keyrelease_action_map_.at(e.key.keysym.scancode) << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
    catch (std::exception ex)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}


void Controller::SetContext(std::shared_ptr<ControllerContext> context_)
{
    controller_context_ = context_;
}
```

ControllerContext.h

```
#ifndef SHMUPPY_HEADER_CONTROLLER_CONTEXT_H
#define SHMUPPY_HEADER_CONTROLLER_CONTEXT_H


#include <map>
#include <functional>

struct ControllerContext
{
    std::map<std::string, std::function<void(void)>> keypress_events_;
    std::map<std::string, std::function<void(void)>> keyrelease_events_;
};


#endif
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit: Tested implementations below.**

As jason says, returning either `0` or `1`, looks like `boolean`. Change `int` to `bool` and return `true` or `false`.

Drop the `std::string` layer. It doesn't add anything over `enum`. And `enum` are just as readable and there is no way typos can appear with `enums`.

I don't have any experience with SDL myself, but I've written a keyboard -> action controller in an attempt at a game.

I'd also like to drop the `std::map` in favor of a `std::vector`. The trick is to use continuous `enums` and use those as indices for the `std::vector`.

Something like this:

```
enum class KeyboardEvents : byte
{
    ON_RELEASE,
    ON_PRESS,

    ORDINAL
};

typedef std::function<void(void)> keyboardFunc_t;

std::vector<keyboardFunc_t> keyboardEvents(KeyboardEvents::ORDINAL);

void bindControls()
{
    auto onReleaseLambda = [&]()
    {
        // Do stuff
    };
    auto onPressLambda = [&]()
    {
        // Do stuff
    };

    // Bind with lambdas
    keyboardEvents[KeyboardEvents::ON_RELEASE] = onReleaseLambda;
    keyboardEvents[KeyboardEvents::ON_PRESS] = onPressLambda;

    // Alternatively, use std::bind
    keyboardEvents[KeyboardEvents::ON_RELEASE] = std::bind(&ClassName::onRelease, classInstancePtr);
    keyboardEvents[KeyboardEvents::ON_PRESS] = std::bind(&ClassName::onPress, classInstancePtr);
}
```

I just wrote this on the top off my head. I'm not sure if it'll compile, but you get the idea.

I would also prefer `lambdas` in favor of `std::bind`.

As for storing `std::shared_ptr<ControllerContext> controller_context_;` in a `raw` or `shared_ptr`, I'd say neither. But **DO** use `std::unique_ptr`. Using a `unique_ptr` will make sure your controller class is not default copyable, which is a good thing when dealing with limited resources.

Like this `std::unique_ptr<ControllerContext> controller_context_;`

**Edit: From here and on:**

Note, don't look too closely on `main.cpp`, it was mainly copied from somewhere to get SDL2 running.

ControllerContext.h:

```
#ifndef SHMUPPY_HEADER_CONTROLLER_CONTEXT_H
#define SHMUPPY_HEADER_CONTROLLER_CONTEXT_H


#include <vector>
#include <functional>

struct ControllerContext
{

    ControllerContext()
        : keyPressEvents(SDL_NUM_SCANCODES)
        , keyReleaseEvents(SDL_NUM_SCANCODES)
    {
        keyPressEvents.resize(SDL_NUM_SCANCODES);
        keyReleaseEvents.resize(SDL_NUM_SCANCODES);
    }

    typedef std::function<void(void)>   KeyboardFunc_t;
    typedef std::vector<KeyboardFunc_t> KeyEvents;

    KeyEvents   keyPressEvents;
    KeyEvents   keyReleaseEvents;
};


typedef std::unique_ptr<ControllerContext>  ControllerContext_ptr;

#endif
```

keyboardcontroller.h:

```
#ifndef SHMUPPY_HEADER_KEYBOARDCONTROLLER_H_
#define SHMUPPY_HEADER_KEYBOARDCONTROLLER_H_

#include <map>
#include <SDL.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>
#include <string>
#include <memory>


#include "ControllerContext.h"



class Controller
{
public:
    Controller();

    bool OnKeyPress(const SDL_Event &e);

    bool OnKeyRelease(const SDL_Event &e);

    // Clear by setting empty func
    void SetReleaseCallback(SDL_Scancode code, const ControllerContext::KeyboardFunc_t & func);
    void SetPressCallback(SDL_Scancode code, const ControllerContext::KeyboardFunc_t & func);

    // Clear both press and release
    void ClearCallback(SDL_Scancode code);

protected:
    ControllerContext_ptr controller_context_;
};


#endif
```

keyboardcontroller.cpp:

```
#include "KeyboardController.h"
#include "ControllerContext.h"


Controller::Controller()
    : controller_context_(new ControllerContext())
{
    //Some test initializations
    auto leftPress = [&]()
    {
        // Left press lambda
        int debug=0;
    };
    auto leftRelease = [&]()
    {
        // Left release lambda
        int debug=0;
    };

    SetPressCallback(SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT, leftPress);
    SetReleaseCallback(SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT, leftRelease);
}

bool Controller::OnKeyPress(const SDL_Event &e)
{
    const auto & scancode = e.key.keysym.scancode;

    const auto & pressFunc = controller_context_->keyPressEvents[scancode];

    if (pressFunc)
    {
        // Call callback if valid
        pressFunc();
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

bool Controller::OnKeyRelease(const SDL_Event &e)
{
    const auto & scancode = e.key.keysym.scancode;

    const auto & pressFunc = controller_context_->keyReleaseEvents[scancode];

    if (pressFunc)
    {
        // Call callback if valid
        pressFunc();

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

void Controller::SetReleaseCallback(SDL_Scancode code, const ControllerContext::KeyboardFunc_t & func)
{
    controller_context_->keyReleaseEvents[code] = func; 
}

void Controller::SetPressCallback(SDL_Scancode code, const ControllerContext::KeyboardFunc_t & func)
{
    controller_context_->keyPressEvents[code] = func;
}

void Controller::ClearCallback(SDL_Scancode code)
{
    controller_context_->keyPressEvents[code] = ControllerContext::KeyboardFunc_t();
    controller_context_->keyReleaseEvents[code] = ControllerContext::KeyboardFunc_t();
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <iostream>

class TestMain
{
    public:
        void handlePressW()
        {
            // W press
            int debug=0;
        }
        void handleReleaseW()
        {
            // W release
            int debug=0;
        }
};

#include "keyboardcontroller.h"

int _stdcall WinMain(struct HINSTANCE__ *hInstance, struct HINSTANCE__ *hPrevInstance, char *lpszCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING) < 0)
    {
        /* Handle problem */
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", SDL_GetError());
    }
    SDL_Window* window = SDL_CreateWindow("Window caption", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 852, 480, 0);
    if (window == NULL)
    {
        /* Handle problem */
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_Quit();
    }
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, 0);
    if (renderer == NULL)
    {
        /* Handle problem */
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", SDL_GetError());
        SDL_Quit();
    }


    Controller keycontroller;

    // Bind testmain methods
    TestMain testmain;
    keycontroller.SetPressCallback(SDL_SCANCODE_W, std::bind(&TestMain::handlePressW, testmain));
    keycontroller.SetReleaseCallback(SDL_SCANCODE_W, std::bind(&TestMain::handleReleaseW, testmain));


    bool running = true;
    while (running)
    {
        /* Clear the buffer of color, setting it to black */
        SDL_RenderClear(renderer);

        /* Draw the buffer into the window */
        SDL_RenderPresent(renderer);

        /* Handle input and events: */
        SDL_Event sdl_event;
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&sdl_event) > 0)
        {
            switch (sdl_event.type)
            {
                case(SDL_KEYDOWN):
                {
                    keycontroller.OnKeyPress(sdl_event);
                    break;
                }

                case(SDL_KEYUP):
                {
                    keycontroller.OnKeyRelease(sdl_event);
                    break;
                }


                case(SDL_QUIT):
                    running = false;
                    break;
            }

        }

        /* Run your logic. For example: */
    }

    SDL_Quit();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Code Review. You've passed though the first-post review queue with flying colours!

Comment: @rolfl: Thank you very much. I just hope this will be of any help to OP and/or any other.

Comment: @Kent it is helpful, but I am having a hard time understanding some of it. For example, you suggest using a `unique_ptr` for the `ControllerContext` object, but in your `bindControls()` method you're bypassing the `ControllerContext` object and setting the methods straight to a vector of functions. I'm assuming that both of those get stuck into my `ControllerContext` object? 
I also don't quite understand the enum class. What is `ORDINAL`? The number of keys on the keyboard? And by using the enums ON_RELEASE and ON_PRESS, only two methods can be assigned to the vector?

Comment: @DanielMartin: That code was more pseudolike code to show how I'd do it. The `ORDINAL` in the enum is number of actions you have, though when I come to think of it, actions should be `KEY_A`, `KEY_E` and so on. I'll update my code with real code soon.

Comment: @DanielMartin: I've added some more code.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense! I can even set up a class a handful of variables to hold the value of the keys the player sets up in game, something like `auto ActionKey = //whatever key the player sets it to in some method`, then when constructing the Contexts I can just do something like `keyReleaseEvents[ActionKey] = somefunc`, and I don't have to worry about strings anymore.

Answer (score 2):

Your `OnKeyPress` and `OnKeyRelease` methods return 1 or 0.
That looks suspiciously as true or false,
in which case `bool` would be the correct return type,
with `true` and `false` as the returned values.

I don't understand the need for this mapping chain logic:
`SDL_Scancode` -> `std::string` -> `std::function<void(void)>`.
It seems you could cut out the string in the middle,
and use `SDL_Scancode` -> `std::function<void(void)>` directly.

Comment: The chaining of `SDL_Scancode` -> `std::string` -> `std::function<void(void)>` was to get a layout of the controller, but support different actions across different states. For example, if I set my space key -> "Action", then in the game state I could do "Action"->ShootMethod, in the pause state I could do "Action"->Accept, etc etc. This way the player could set up the controller to behave the same way across states, instead of the controller only behaving one way for one state(Action button only does actions in gameplay, but action button does nothing if I bring up the pause menu? Lame)

Answer (score 1):

This is silly:

> ```
> int Controller::OnKeyRelease(const SDL_Event& e) 
> {
>     try
>     {
>         std::cout << keyrelease_action_map_.at(e.key.keysym.scancode) << std::endl;
>         return 1;
>     }
>     catch (std::exception ex)
>     {
>         return 0;
>     } 
> }
> ```

If you don't want to use exceptions, then don't call `at()`. Catching the exception to return an error code is a clear sign that `at()` is not what you want. You should use `find()` instead:

```
bool Controller::OnKeyRelease(const SDL_Event& e)
{
    const auto entry = keyrelease_action_map_.find(e.key.keysym.scancode);
    if (entry == std::end(keyrelease_action_map_))
    {
        return false;
    }

    std::cout << entry->second << std::endl;
    return true;
}
```

---

<strike>That being said, I would actually prefer the exception approach in this case, keeping `at()` but letting the error propagate to the caller.</strike>  Well, not necessarily. If a value not being present in the map is an *exceptional* thing, then propagating the exception is adequate. If a value is only optionally in the map, then testing with `find()` would be the adequate approach, with the optional `return false` with it.

If you do keep the return code to signal error, then at the very least use a boolean. Integer error codes are very prone to confusion and there isn't a single agreement on meaning. E.g.: on Unix, some system calls return 0 on success and -1 on error, while others threat the value as boolean and return 0 or 1. Madness, I say!

Comment: _That being said, I would actually prefer the exception approach in this case, keeping at() but letting the error propagate to the caller._

Something like this, where the try-catch is wrapped around the call to the function, rather than within the function itself ?

http://ideone.com/ci6gAp

Comment: @DanielMartin, certainly not like that. Handle the exception if there is a way to recover from the error, otherwise let the program terminate.

Comment: In both examples what is being done is to convert the exception to an error code, so that it can be ignored. This is not error handling and a violation of the [fail fast principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fail-fast) by not letting the error propagate and terminate the program.

Comment: I see, I just misunderstood you then. I'll switch to using `find()`, since I don't want the program to terminate if they press a button on the keyboard but there is no method attached to it. Although I am curious what you mean to let the error propagate to the caller.

Comment: @DanielMartin Ah, okay, so I also misinterpreted your code. I thought that a key not being in the map was a more serious error, judging by your use of exceptions. If a key is optionally on the map, then `find` is really what you should be using. `at` is for when you want to either get a value or fail with a hard error (the exception).